# Updating a table in oracle from another table with duplicate records present

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, lets say table books and table authors.

Table books has 4 fields, BookId, Title, Author, Publisher

Table authors has 5 field AuthorID, Title, Author, Publisher, Price

I want to update book to have the price field from authors. There is no one unique key so the criteria is if Title or Author or Publisher match then add that price to books. In my case authors has many duplicate values in Title, Author or Publisher so I get update errors because of duplicates. So basically how in oracle can I update books with that criteria and in case of duplicates just choose any record, it doesn't matter which and put it in there? Other languages have the top command that you can use to do such a thing but it looks like Oracle lack that.

I have tried various merge and update statements on my own with no luck.  Something like:

```
   UPDATE books n
   set n.price = (
   select t.price from authors t where 
   n.title= t.title or
   n.author = t.author or
   n.publisher = t.publisher)
```

But that statement isn't checking for duplicates and stopping them thus failing so I am missing that key.

Comment: This requirement makes no sense. If a book in BOOKS table matches a row in AUTHORS table by publisher, show *as the price of this book* a price for ANY book (some random one) ever published by that publisher? Why would you ever do something like that?

Comment: I don't make the tables I just do what they ask. I agree this is stupid.

Comment: @mathguy I know... sometimes I feel like an enabler by answering questions on how to do bad things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way is:

```
 UPDATE books n
   set n.price = (
   select t.price from authors t where 
   ( n.title= t.title or
   n.author = t.author or
   n.publisher = t.publisher )
   and rownum = 1)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm thanks. I googled it and your method basically was the work around for lack of top so that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot `rownum = 1` is not obvious step